# Fisher's & McNemar's tests

Tags: fishers-exact-test, mcnemar-test

I'm conducting a retrospective study to assess the efficacy of a new test for predicting sudden cardiac death (SCD). I also want to compare the accuracy of my new predictor with that of a conventional predictor. I'm not a statistician, so I would very much appreciate it if any of you experts can confirm that I'm in the right direction w.r.t the statistical tests I need to use.

1. I'm planning to use Fisher's exact test to see if my new predictor is associated with occurrence of SCD. That is, I will divide my sample of patients into two groups, one group in which patients died of SCD, and the other in which no one died of SCD, and I will compare between the two groups the proportion of patients in which my predictor was positive. Am I using the Fisher's test appropriately here?
2. I'm planning to use McNemar's test to compare the accuracy of my new predictor with that of the conventional predictor. That is, I will have a 2x2 contingency table with the following entries:

   Top left cell: # patients in which both predictors accurately determined 
                whether or not they died of SCD. 
   Top right cell: # patients in which my predictor was accurate but the 
                conventional predictor was not. 
   Bottom left cell: # patients in which my predictor was not accurate but the 
                  conventional predictor was. 
   Bottom right cell: # patients in which both predictors were inaccurate.

Is my use of McNemar's test correct?

Comment: I don't see a problem in your approach. Don't forget the descriptive part though.

Comment: Are these predictors truly binary or are you dichotomizing them?

Comment: Yes, these predictors are truly binary.